# How to plot $SO(3)$ to unit sphere?

Tags: lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices

I understand that an $SO(3)$ elements corresponds to a $3 \times  3$ rotation matrix, and it could be mapped to $\omega \in \mathfrak{so}(3)$ (lie algebra), quaternion and Euler angles.

But how to plot an $SO(3)$ element to unit sphere (2-sphere or $S_2$)? Since many paper visualised $SO(3)$ on a sphere, e.g.:

1. Figure.1 in Evan, S. Gawlik, Embedding-Based Interpolation on the Special Orthogonal Group
2. Figure 2. in T. Shingel, Interpolation in Special Orthogonal Groups.

Current, I apply a rotation to three axes $\{1,0,0\}$, $\{0,1,0\}$, and $\{0,0,1\}$ respectively and subsequently an $SO(3)$ element corresponds to three points on the sphere instead of one.

Comment: You could model it as the set of ordered pairs of orthogonal points on the sphere I think

Comment: Do you mean the three orthogonal axes appearing in many 3D software?

Comment: Both of your referenced figures clearly explain in their captions: what is being plotted is just the action of the rotations on a fixed vector; i.e. $R(t)v_0$ where $R(t) \in SO(3)$ and $v_0 \in S^2$.

Comment: $\text{SO}(3)$ is a fibre bundle over $S^2$ (with fibre $S^1$).

Comment: Thank Anthony and Evgeny for making the plotting method clear. But I do not think such plot always gives an intuitively-correct visualisation.

Comment: I don't need to answer your question, since Anthony Carapetis has already done that. I just wanted to call your a attention to a confusion that you have shown us. You seem to think that there is a natural map from $SO(3)$ into $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Actually, it's the other way around: there is a natural map (the exponential map) from $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ onto $SO(3)$.

Comment: You may enjoy this somewhat ancient Java applet by programmer / science fiction author, Greg Egan. [SO(3)](http://www.gregegan.net/APPLETS/01/01.html)

Comment: It's possible to identify $SO(3)$ with points on the unit ball, with antipodal boundary points identified. The line going through the origin and a given point is the axis, and the (signed) distance of the point from the centre gives the angle of rotation about that axis. As has been mentioned, since $SO(3)$ has dimension 3, and the unit sphere has dimension 2, there won't be a nice identification between these.